# What type of border is preferred for high pass or low pass filtering?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

When high or low pass filters are being applied to an (grayscale) image, the borders need to be handled separately. They could be filled with 0's or 255's (b/w), repeat the nearest pixel value, or even the image could be repeated.

How do the different border-handling-methods impact the result of he filtering operations? Which way should be preferred for which type of filter (HPF or LPF) and why?

OpenCV for example has various [BorderTypes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga209f2f4869e304c82d07739337eae7c5) like `BORDER_REPLICATE` or `BORDER_CONSTANT` but I can't find any information about what's the best choice for which filter.

Comment: I really feel this question is more suited to https://dsp.stackexchange.com as it's more of a image processing theory question than programming.

Comment: Since every piece of image processing software has a different default boundary handling, you can safely assume that there is no single best method. Each method has pros and cons, and it depends on the application which one you would chose. If you are going to ask this question on DSP.SE, make sure you frame it by specifying a particular application, a particular reason for filtering.